# Redirect and reset from one html page to another one

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, reset

I need to redirect from my destination.xhtml to my index.xhtml, making a reset to the inputText in this last one page.

The problem is, I need inputText not to be automatically reset when I normally refresh my index, just in the case it is redirected from my destination.xhtml

Thank you all.

I come from:

```
<h:body>
    <f:view>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel value="UserID: "/><h:outputText value="#{userMBean.user_login}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="Activation code: "/><h:outputText id="act_code" value="#{userMBean.act_code}" style="color:red"/><br></br>
            <h:message for="act_code"/>
            <h:commandButton action="index" value="Back"/>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
```

And in my index I have:

```
 <h:form>
        <h:inputText required="true" value="#{userMBean.user_login}">
            <f:validator validatorId="tencko.model.EmailValidator"/> 
        </h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton action="#{logicBean.lookingfor()}" value="Search"/>

    </h:form>
```

Comment: Can you give some more detail, such as the code on destination.xhtml and index.xhtml?

Answer (score 0):

Base the replacing logic on the Referrer (the page where the user comes from). In javascript you get it like this

```
var ref = document.referrer
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.referrer) for more information

Comment: Sure, I go for it in the principal post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem just setting the Manage Bean user login to null, then when I return index from my Logic Bean, that value is just null, so it looks reset, but it's just that value, all the Manage Bean object keeps being the same as before, until you start another search.

Thank you all anyway.

```
MBean userVO = (MBean) ve.getValue(context);


    // Reset login used
    userVO.setUser_login(null);        

    return "index";
```